# #each helper in Handlebars isn't iterating over keys with brackets

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I use Handlebars in my Node.js/Express application. I have JSON with a few keys with square brackets - `tools[]` etc.

I can pass these keys normally to Handlebars using quotation marks `{{'tools[]'}}` and the app returns valid values.

When I try to iterate over values whose key is in quotation marks - 
`{{#each 'tools[]'}}Something here...{{/each}}` I can't get any result.

Is it bug? Do I use wrong syntax?

Possible solution might be to change keys in JSON (not to use square brackets). But these brackets are necessary to get multiplevalues from checkboxes in form with `enctype=multipart/form-data` and it would be verry painful to change all those keys.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the handlebars [docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#basic-blocks):

> You may not include a closing ] in a path-literal, but all other
>   characters are fair game.

So your only way is to use a subexpression. You can use the builtin `lookup` helper inside `#each`.

> Handlebars offers support for subexpressions, which allows you to
>   invoke multiple helpers within a single mustache, and pass in the
>   results of inner helper invocations as arguments to outer helpers.
>   Subexpressions are delimited by parentheses.

```
{{#each (lookup this "tools[]")}}
    {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

```js
const data = {
  "tools[]": [1,2,3,4]
};

const template = `
  {{#each (lookup this "tools[]")}}
    tools[{{@index}}]: {{this}}
  {{/each}}`;
  

console.log(Handlebars.compile(template)(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```